# Starting QGIS 3.4 with own startup.py faults on Mac OSX Catalina

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Created file startup.py:

```
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
qgs.exitQgis()
```

and saved in "Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3" (The example taken from [PyQGIS Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html)).

Trying to start QGIS 3.4 under macOS Catalina I get a message in separate window "No Data Providers:

No QGIS data provider plugins found in:

No vector layers can be loaded. Check your QGIS installation.

After I close this window QGIS crashes.
If I delete startup.py QGIS starts it's right way.

What is the reason of that error?